# javascript function for circular photo slideshow autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, function, multidimensional-array, slideshow

I made a simple slideshow using javascript. But it doesn't work properly. I need 3 photos to display first time and then slide one by one. But in my code, after all the images are finished it redirects back to the first image.

This is the code,

```
const images = [
  { id: 1, src: Image1, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 2, src: Image2, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 3, src: Image3, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 4, src: Image4, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 5, src: Image5, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 6, src: Image6, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 7, src: Image7, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 8, src: Image8, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 9, src: Image9, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 10, src: Image10, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
  { id: 11, src: Image11, title: "foo", description: "bar" },
];
const delay = 5000;

const Slideshow = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        setIndex((prevIndex) =>
          prevIndex === images.length
          ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
    );

    return () => {};
  }, [index]);
};
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I added react. Looks like that is important

Comment: Of course it does because when `index` reaches `images.length`  it is then reset to `0`